# Passing an individual element value to a list using function

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I am trying to pass an value on an "Empty" list(myUniqueList = []) using a user- defined function,
where I need to design it in a manner that in case I passed a value that is already existing in my
"empty" list, that value will then be added or append to the other "empty" list(myLeftovers = [] ).

```
def append_1(value):
    myUniqueList.append(value)
    
def append_2(value):
    myLeftovers.append(value)
    
myUniqueList = []
myLeftovers = []    

n = int(input("Enter number of elements: "))

for i in range(n):
    value = input("Enter a value: ")
    for item in myUniqueList:
        if item == value:
            append_2(value)
        else:
            append_1(value)

print(myUniqueList)
print(myLeftovers)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myUniqueList = [] 
myLeftovers = []

def append_1(value):
    myUniqueList.append(value)

def append_2(value): 
    myLeftovers.append(value)

n = int(input("Enter number of elements: "))

for i in range(n):
    value = input("Enter a value: ")
    if not value in myUniqueList:
        append_1(value)
    else:
        append_2(value)

print(myUniqueList) 
print(myLeftovers)
```

This should be what you are looking for. If you write the code without the two functions i think is better. Hope this will be helpful!

```
myUniqueList = [] 
myLeftovers = []

n = int(input("Enter number of elements: "))

for i in range(n):
    value = input("Enter a value: ")
    if not value in myUniqueList:
        myUniqueList.append(value)
    else:
        myLeftovers.append(value)

print(myUniqueList) 
print(myLeftovers)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.